# error with fseek

Tags: c

With the following code, I attempt to read 4 bytes from a file:

```
FILE *f

uint32_t read_program(int A)
{
    long i;
    uint32_t strofprog;
    uint8_t tmp;
    i = 4*A;
    fseek(f,i,0);// set a position in file
    if((tmp = getc(f)) != EOF)
    {
        while((i%(4*A)) < 4)
        {
            fseek(f, i, SEEK_SET);
            tmp = getc(f);
            strofprog = tmp;
            strofprog <<= 8;
            i++;
        }
        return strofprog;
    }
    else
    { 
        fclose(f);
        return -1; 
    };
}
```

However, when I run it, it results in the following error:

```
main.c: In function ‘read_program’:
main.c:77: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘fseek’
/usr/include/stdio.h:722: note: expected ‘struct FILE *’ but argument is of type ‘FILE’
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is this the real code? Check the declaration of `f`.

Comment: yes.  The declaration of f is FILE *f; then f=fopen("file.bin", "r");

Comment: `if((tmp = getc(f)) != EOF)` is only correct if `tmp` is declared as an `int`! Also your inside loop doesn't check if `tmp` is `EOF` either

Comment: where is it? Can you cut and paste your file directly as it is?

Comment: Check that you haven't typed `*f` in one of the `fseek()` calls.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/930813/ - there is full code

Answer (score 2):

Line 85 in the paste:

```
fseek(*f,i,0);// set a position in file
```

as suspected by @unwind.